# Gulp-sass not piping

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

Trying to write my gulpfile.js in the newer syntax. My html is piping fine, but my sass isn't compiling/piping? I'm not sure which because I'm not getting any errors.

```js
const { series, src, dest } = require('gulp');
const gulpSass = require('gulp-sass');
gulpSass.compiler = require('node-sass');
function html(cb) {
    src('./src/*.html')
        .pipe(dest('dist'))
    cb();
}
function sass(cb) {
    src('.src/sass/*')
        .pipe(gulpSass())
        .pipe(dest('./dist/css'))
    cb();
}
exports.default = series(html, sass);
```

Comment: The `src` glob is missing a forward slash. I believe `'./src/sass/*'` should work.

Comment: I feel so dumb. Thank you very much!